# Java Spring Project on a Wildfly Server can't access RESTful Services

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, macos, rest

I have a java app running a Spring application with RESRful services.

**Windows**

I have a Windows environment with Eclipse and a JBoss Wildfly server integrated.

[image]

The RESful services can be accessed successfully, via e.g. http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly/category/list.

**OSX**

I have recently started to migrate this to an OSX environment. I have Eclipse and a Wildfly server installed.

[image]

I can access http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly/ which shows the server welcome page. However, I cannot access the RESTful service, via e.g. http://localhost:8080/jbosswildfly/category/list (`ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED`)

**Question**

How do I get the RESTful services to work on in the OSX environment?

**More info**

As you can see, in the Windows environment, under the `jbosswildfly` server, there is a `spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar`, which is not present in the OSX environment.

In the Windows environment, I created the Java project from scratch, but in the OSX environment, I imported the existing project from an OpenShift Git repository. The source code in the two environments are identical.

The project is built with Maven and has all the required dependencies.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <!-- <parent> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId> 
        <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version> </parent> -->

    <groupId>jbosswildfly</groupId>
    <artifactId>jbosswildfly</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>jbosswildfly</name>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>eap</id>
            <url>http://maven.repository.redhat.com/techpreview/all</url>
            <releases>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </releases>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>true</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.fork>true</maven.compiler.fork>
        <project.build.directory>${project.basedir}/target</project.build.directory>
        <springframework.version>4.3.1.RELEASE</springframework.version>
        <hibernate.version>5.2.1.Final</hibernate.version>
        <mysql.connector.version>5.1.31</mysql.connector.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <jackson.version>2.4.2</jackson.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax</groupId>
            <artifactId>javaee-api</artifactId>
            <version>7.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>${mysql.connector.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework</groupId> <artifactId>spring-oxm</artifactId> 
            <version>${springframework.version}</version> </dependency> -->

        <!-- Spring boot -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.5.RELEASE</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${springframework.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Hibernate -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>${hibernate.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>joda-time</groupId> <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId> 
            <version>1.6.2</version> <type>jar</type> </dependency> -->

        <!-- jsr303 validation -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet+JSP+JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.0-b01</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet.jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2-b02</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- JSON -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
            <version>${jackson.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20160810</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Sockets -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.corundumstudio.socketio</groupId>
            <artifactId>netty-socketio</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.opennlp</groupId>
            <artifactId>opennlp-tools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Test -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.skyscreamer</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsonassert</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- When built in OpenShift the 'openshift' profile will be used when 
                invoking mvn. -->
            <!-- Use this profile for any OpenShift specific customization your app 
                will need. -->
            <!-- By default that is to put the resulting archive into the 'deployments' 
                folder. -->
            <!-- http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-building-for-different-environments.html -->
            <id>openshift</id>
            <build>
                <finalName>jbosswildfly</finalName>
                <plugins>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>1.0.2.Final</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <outputDirectory>webapps</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>2.3</version>
                        <configuration>
                            <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                            <outputDirectory>deployments</outputDirectory>
                            <warName>ROOT</warName>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId> 
                        </plugin> -->
                    <!-- <plugin> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                        </plugin> -->


                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</project>
```

**UPDATE**

One thing I have noticed is that in the Windows environment, the `target` folder contains a number of generated artifacts, but in the OSX environment, there is noting in the `target` folder.

Comment: What happens if, in your Eclipse,  you right click on your project and do a Maven > Update project , and then republish to the server ?

Comment: Thanks Val Bonn, I gave that a try, but when I try access the RESTful service, I get: 404 - Not Found

Comment: And the spring-web-4.3.1.jar still does not appear under the jbosswildfly ?  Are you sure you see this jar in your project tree, under Java Resources > Libraries > Maven dependencies ? Can you find this library under the "target" directory on your file system ? And, on your server, can you try to "Add and remove" the app ?

Comment: The `spring-web-4.3.1.jar` still does not appear under the jbosswildfly. I have also just checked the `target` folder, and it is empty in the OSX env.

Comment: Then it means that your project is not built. Try to run a maven clean install.

Comment: Thank you, I think you pointed me in the right direction. I don't have Maven installed on the OSX machine.

Answer (score 1):

As you notices in your UPDATE, if the `target` is empty, it is because the project did not compile.

You have to install maven on your OSX.

Comment: I have just installed maven. I ran `mvn clean install` from the terminal and it built successfully. There are now also artifacts in the `target` folder generated from the build. However, I still cannot access the RESTful services (`not found`). Also, the `spring-web-4.3.1.RELEASE.jar` is not showing up under `jbosswildfly` in the server in Eclipse. I have also tried `Maven -> Update Project` in Eclipse.